# Vectorized function with data.table

Tags: r, data.table, purrr

I am trying to write a vectorized function. Here is pseudocode using the data.frame "final".
BID_AMOUNT/Duration * Probability * bill_factor

where bill_factor is retrieved from the data.frame "schedule". Each row's bill_factor is identified by the Duration and the Number_Sequence. For row 1 this would be schedule[3,1]. For row 2 this would be schedule[3,2], etc.

This seems like an iteration problem that could be solved using one of the apply functions. I also considered using function map2 from the purrr package. I can't get anything to work.

Expected result: I would like a function which will retrieve data from schedule for any combination of Duration/Number_Sequence.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

- BS

```
library(data.table)
#create data
data <- structure(list(OPPORTUNITY_ID = c(28249800L, 28249800L, 28249800L,28249845L, 28249845L, 28249845L, 28249845L, 28312677L, 28312677L,28312677L, 28312677L, 28312677L)
               , Number_Sequence = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L)
               , BID_AMOUNT = c(1700000, 1700000, 1700000, 2250000, 2250000, 2250000, 2250000, 1100000, 1100000, 1100000, 1100000, 1100000)
               , Probability = c(30L, 30L, 30L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L), Duration = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L))
          , row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")
          , sorted = "OPPORTUNITY_ID")

#reorder and clean up column names. 
setcolorder(data, c('OPPORTUNITY_ID', 'BID_AMOUNT', 'Probability', 'Duration'))
data$Probability <- data$Probability/100

#create column bill_factor
data$bill_factor <-  c(rep(.33,3), rep(.25, 4), rep(.2, 5))

#create schedule of payments
schedule <- structure(list(`0` = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L,11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, NA, NA, NA, NA),
               `1` = c(1, 0.5, 0.33, 0.25, 0.2, 0.17, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.02, NA, NA, NA, NA)
               , `2` = c(NA, 0.5, 0.33, 0.25, 0.2, 0.17, 0.15, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, NA, NA, NA, NA)
               , `3` = c(NA, NA, 0.33, 0.25, 0.2, 0.17, 0.25, 0.2, 0.15, 0.1, 0.1, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, NA, NA, NA, NA)
               , `4` = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.25, 0.2, 0.17, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.15, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.08, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, NA, NA, NA, NA)
               , `5` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.2, 0.17, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.2, 0.2, 0.15, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.03, NA, NA, NA, NA)
               , `6` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.17, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.08, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, NA, NA, NA, NA)
               , `7` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.15, 0.15, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.05, 0.05, NA, NA, NA, NA)
               , `8` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.05, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.15, 0.15, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.05, NA, NA, NA, NA)
               , `9` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.05, 0.05, 0.1, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.1, 0.08, 0.08, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.08, NA, NA, NA, NA)
               , `10` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.1, NA, NA, NA, NA)
               , `11` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.08, 0.1, NA, NA, NA, NA)
               , `12` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.08, NA, NA, NA, NA)
               , `13` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, NA, NA, NA, NA)
               , `14` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.05, 0.05, 0.03, 0.03, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, NA, NA, NA, NA)
               , `15` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, NA, NA, NA, NA)
               , `16` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.05, NA, NA, NA, NA)
               , `17` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, NA, NA, NA, NA)
               , `18` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, NA, NA, NA, NA)
               , `19` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, NA, NA, NA, NA)
               , `20` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, NA, NA, NA, NA)
               , `21` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, NA, NA, NA, NA)
               , `22` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, NA, NA, NA, NA)
               , `23` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.03, 0.03, NA, NA, NA, NA)
               , `24` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.01, NA, NA, NA, NA)
               , Total = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA))
          , row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
schedule <- schedule[,!26]
schedule <- schedule[,!1]

#set colnames to 1 indexing
colnames(schedule) = as.character(c(1:24))

#create results column
results <- data[,.(result = BID_AMOUNT/Duration*Probability*bill_factor), by=OPPORTUNITY_ID]



final <- cbind(data,results)
final <- final[,!7]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the bill_factor column in your data frame with the apply function. Just pass schedule as an extra argument to the apply function:

```
data$bill_factor <- apply(data, 
                          1, 
                          function(x, s) s[[x["Duration"], x["Number_Sequence"]]], 
                          s=schedule)
```